# Exchange data from Microsoft Business Central to JavaScript

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, microsoft-dynamics-nav, dynamics-al

Curerntly I'am working on a scanner that inputs data into BC fields. The communication between the device and the software is in javascript. 
 I can send data from JS to BC with

```
 Microsoft.Dynamics.NAV.InvokeExtensibilityMethod('BarcodeRead',[BCode] );
```

but I couldn't figure out how to send data back to JS. 
 (The reader has a screen, and I need to display warehouse inventory on it based on BC data).

My current best guess would be to send data with *STREAMS* to a *.txt* file, and the JS code read from that. But that would be slow and not so reliable in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

As you know allready that *InvokeExtensibilityMethod* can trigger *events* on the BC side, you know that you need a  [Control Add-In](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-control-addin-object).

On the Microsoft Docs page about Control Add-Ins, there is an example which shows you how to call JS functions from BC:

```
    // The procedure declarations specify what JavaScript methods could be called from AL.
    // In main.js code, there should be a global function CallJavaScript(i,s,d,c) {Microsoft.Dynamics.NAV.InvokeExtensibilityMethod('CallBack', [i, s, d, c]);}
    procedure CallJavaScript(i: integer; s: text; d: decimal; c: char);
```

In BC lingo, *procedures* are kind of the opposite of *events*.